# Handling referenced objects from JSON Objects

Tags: json, jackson

I am using Jackson as a mapper for a REST Service. A sample json response is

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "name": "One fine name",
   "child": 1 //this is a primary key referencing a composite object
}
```

Now, using Jackson to map this notation into POJOs, the class would probably look like the following

```
class Parent{
    protected Integer id;
    protected String name;
    protected Child child;

    //....
    //appropriate Getters and Setters
}
```

But when Jackson is about to deserialize the object, it complains about converting an integer into the Child object. Any idea how to make Jackson understand that the value for the child field is a reference?

Comment: Can you share your serialization code?  Looks to me like [this](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureObjectIdentity) should do it, curious what you're doing.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the response but Jackson isn't doing the serialisation. I am using Jackson to DEserialise a json response from  a REST service.

Comment: I get that, sorry I wrote in a sloppy manner.  I just meant, are you de-serializing with objectMapper.readValue(json, Identifiable.class) like in the link? Also, it might help to try serializing and then de-serializing back.  If you can't serialize to the JSON format you're reading, then you can't expect to de-serialize the other direction.

Comment: you can write custom deserializer to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks guys. After more digging, I just upgraded my jackson-databind version (2.0.2) to the latest version (2.5.4) and it worked well.